# Wordpress 3.5 Media Manager - Default view to "Uploaded to this post"

Tags: media-library

I'm trying to figure out how to default the select box above the media gallery in the new media manager so that it shows the images "uploaded to this post" by default. I can't seem to find a way that works properly.

Thx folks.

Comment: Please ask your second separate question as a second separate question.

Comment: Hi Toscho, I'm removed my second question but don't see any similar posts to above that answer this question. I don't believe its duplicate. IF you've seen a similar question answered can you share the link. Thanks!

Comment: The answer to that question does what you are asking for.

Comment: sorry...the answer to what question?

Comment: It makes the files uploaded to post the default view.

Comment: Did you mean to post a link to the correct answer? Don't see it in your response. Thanks

Comment: The grey block on top of your question contains the link.

Comment: Duh sorry. Didnt see that. A bit different UX than I'm used to :) Thanks for pointing that out. I actually tried that but it doesnt work well. It first defaults to ALL MEDIA ITEMS, Then javascript changes it to "Uploaded in this Post", so the page begins loading ALL MEDIA IMAGES first then switches to the proper tab, but continues to load all the images in the hidden tab first. Then after a long delay loads the "uploaded in this post" images. Not ideal and actually also inefficient. The proper way to would be to REORDER the select box so "Uploaded in this post" is first in the dropdown.

Comment: I decided that a different question was really required here. So I created this question for how to reorder the select box. Thx. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98685/wordpress-3-5-media-manager-reorder-selectbox-items-on-media-library-tab